# auth component issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Im trying to get my admin routing working with the auth component. I want the following routing to work.

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

but when i type in /admin it redirects to /admin/users/login and display this error.

```
Create UsersController::admin_login() in file: cms.local/controllers/users_controller.php
```

here is my app_controller code.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar','Auth','Session');

    function beforeFilter(){

        //Set up Auth Component
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'admin_index');
        $this->Auth->allow('display');

    }

}
```

users_controller

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';

    function login(){

    }

    function admin_logout(){
        $this->Session->destroy();
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}
?>
```

If you require more information let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, all works ok :)

In AppController::beforeFilter() you stated that in order to log in, the loginAction is Users/login (Users/admin_login if admin=>true)

when you go to Pages/index with admin=>true and you are not logged in, you are being redirected to Users/admin_login, and as this tells:

> but when i type in /admin it redirects to /admin/users/login and display this error.
>
> `Create UsersController::admin_login() in file: cms.local/controllers/users_controller.php`

The method UsersController::admin_login() is not found and you should create it.

Comment: why do i need two login functions? login and admin_login. I added admin_login, but then it asked for view for it. Does auth component not like admin routing?

Comment: All because of cake convention. If you need the prefix `admin` to work, you really need both `login` and `admin_login` to be there. And corresponding views should also be created, as it's logical that users and admins seeing different login right?

Answer (score 0):

You can force Auth to use the non-prefixed login action by specifying `'admin' => false` in your loginAction. This way, all actions that require authentication will use the non-prefixed login action. So your beforeFilter would look something like this:

```
function beforeFilter(){

    //Set up Auth Component
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'admin_index');
    $this->Auth->allow('display');

}
```

Similarly, you could go the other way and specify 'admin' => true to only use **admin_login**.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me fine:-

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if (isset($this - > params['admin'])) {
        $loggedAdminId = $this - > Session - > read("adminid");
        if (!$loggedAdminId && $this - > params['action'] != "admin_login") {
            $this - > redirect("/admin/admins/login");
            $this - > Session - > setFlash('The URL you followed requires you login.');
        } else {
            $this - > Auth - > allow('*');
        }
    } else {
        $this - > Auth - > loginAction = array('controller' = > 'users', 'action' = > 'login', 'admin' = > false);
        $this - > Auth - > loginRedirect = array('controller' = > 'users', 'action' = > 'admin_index');
    }
}
```